# How to run a particular bash shell script after closing a terminal window?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

By inserting a script in **.bashrc** file, I am able to run that script when new terminal window is created.
Is there any similar method to run a script after closing a terminal?

All I want is to keep the count of number of terminal windows that are currently open. If you have any other method to do it, please tell.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want this count? What do you want to do with this count? Is the number of running terminal processes (findable with `ps`, `pgrep`, etc.) not what you are interested in?

Comment: You can use a combination of `who`, `grep` and `nc -l`.

Comment: Are you counting new terminals, or merely new shells?  If the latter, just put a trap on exit to decrement.  If the former, what technique are you using to detect a new terminal?  Do something similar in the trap.

Comment: @EtanReisner I just want to keep the count of number of open terminals in a file. whenever i open a new terminal(ALT+T .. or by some other method) i want this count to increase and whenever i close a terminal i want this count to decrease. 
I am able to do the former as i added my script in .bashrc file but i'm not able to do the later one.

Comment: Why do you need this in a file? Is `pgrep` when you need the information not a reasonable solution for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to grab a count of PTY's on the system: `ls /dev/pts/  | wc -l`  These should only be active in that directory if they are in use.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above command, its output is above 40 or something  but the number of terminals open in my pc were just 4-5. I didnt understand this. Could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line:

```
ps a | awk '{print $2}' | grep -vi "tty*" | uniq | wc -l
```

first get all processes with *ps*, pipe it to *awk* to get just the second column, use *grep* to ignore the "tty*", omit multiple lines with *uniq* and then count the lines with *wc -l*.

This should do the trick.